# XML class description to C++ class description: a design pattern?

Tags: c++, xml, design-patterns, xml-parsing

I was wondering whether there are any specific design patterns (maybe targeted at C++) for this situation.

I have an XML file containing data in this format:

```
<STH_XML>
<tag1>
    <tag2 id="myId1">
        <tag3 name="type" value="myVal1"/>
        <tag4 name="device" value="myVal2"/>
        <tag5 name="instances" value="myVal3"/>
        <tag6>
            <tag7 id="myId2">
                <specs name="type" value="myVal4"/>
                <specs name="frequency" value="myVal5" unit="MHz"/>
            </tag7>
        </tag6>
    </tag2>
</tag1>
```

Unfortunately, the XSD/DTD of this XML is subject to frequent changes.

I need to automatically convert the XSD/DTD into a series of C++ structures or classes like this:

```
struct tag7
{
   std::string id;
   std::string type;
   std::string frequency;
}

struct tag6
{
   std::set<tag7*> tag6s;
}

struct tag2
{
   std::string id;
   std::string type;
   std::string device;
   std::string instances;
   tag6 elem6; // because I know there is only one from the XSD analysis
}

struct tag1
{
   std::set<tag2> tag2s;
}
```

**What design pattern is best suited to realize this functionality?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure it's a design pattern you need.

I can recommend a programming paradigm, though: code generation.

You can define your structure in XSD/XDD, and automatically generate the C++ `struct`s you need.

Taken a step further, you can define things in a language-agnostic format, and then generate both the XSD and the C++ from that one.  Then, later, if you need to go to, say, C#, you can write the code generator for that.

At its most basic, a code generator reads in a file, parses it, and then "generates" the code through a bunch of print statements on the parsed data.

This process can be made part of your build as a pre-build step.  The generator processes the XSD to spit out C++, and then that C++ is used to build your project the rest of the way.

I think you already knew what you needed to do, but `code generation` is the term for it.

Comment: thank you very much for sharing your insights. In this case, do you know any specific tool already out there to do so with XML/XSD?

Comment: The one I used the last time I did something like this was a Perl script called Jeeves.  It let me specify the output exactly how I wanted it from the ground up.  That's the only way I've done it so far.  But there are lots of XML parsers out there which can be used to parse your XSD.  From there, you know in your mind what C++ you want to generate, so then just iterate through the XSD and `cout` your C++.  I think you'll probably get to where you want to go faster than trying to customize a giant library out of the box.